# Document Insertion with time-weighted postprocessor (Python) Llama Index (GPT Index)

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, llama-index, gpt-index

I want to insert a document (initially text like pdf, docx, etc.) into an existing index w/ [Time-Weighted Rerank](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/node_postprocessor/TimeWeightedPostprocessorDemo.html).

The index is already created with metadata for time-stamping, How can the insertion be conducted for any new data(docs) to insert in the existing one.